# How do I allow users to log in to my web app using their IBM ID

Tags: authentication, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Should be a simple matter of registering the app in the IBM Cloud and providing callback URIs for authenticating the user and returning control just like login with google or login with Amazon.

But I cannot seem to find the exact flow of steps involved.

--prasanna

Answer (score 1):

I think the service you are looking for is **App ID**. 
When you are developing a web application, you can use the App ID web flow to securely authenticate users. Users are then able to access your server-side protected content in your web apps.

App ID uses the OIDC authorization code flow to securely authenticate users. With this flow, when the user is authenticated, the app receives an authorization code. The code is then exchanged for an access, identity, and refresh token. In code exchange step the tokens are always sent via a secure backchannel between the app and the OIDC server. This provides an additional layer of security as the attacker is not able to intercept the tokens. These tokens can be sent directly to the web server hosting application for user authentication.

App ID interacts with identity providers by using multiple protocols such as OpenID Connect, SAML, and more. For example, OpenID Connect is the protocol that is used with many social providers such as Facebook, Google. Enterprise providers such as Azure Active Directory External link icon or Active Directory Federation Service External link icon, generally use SAML as their identity protocol. For Cloud Directory, the service uses SCIM to verify identity information.

Read this [blog post](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/11/new-in-app-id-app-identity-custom-sign-in-methods-and-more/) for using a custom identity provider

For an in-depth understanding of the flow, you can refer to this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/web-apps.html#understanding-the-flow)